# AngularJS $http header for getting token

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to angularJS.
in my angular app, there is a form for login. i checked the API login endpoint on postman and i notice it generates a token after successfully logged in.

I have a form to add blog post.

I want only logged in user can add blog post. below snippet are associate with my add blog form, currently i cant post through this form, coz, it doesn't get authenticated, even if i logged in with my login form.

but it works nice on postman.

I heard of `$http header` but not getting how to implement this.

It falls me in trouble for last 7 days, yet i couldnt fix this issue.

can anyone help to fix this?

Thanks

```
   $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/blog',
            data: $scope.formBlogModel
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.success = 'post success'
        }, function(response) {
            $scope.error = "an error occured";
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `headers` property, also you can implement [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors):

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/blog',
    data: $scope.formBlogModel,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    $scope.success = 'post success'
}, function(response) {
    $scope.error = "an error occured";
});
```

Comment: @mamuncode, What you mean by manually? This is example at case of access token.

Comment: Shouid i copy-past exactly what you put? i guess in 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, i should put api token like 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'adfdskjfdlsfjdsfjdsklfjkdfsdflfjdsfdsf'? this way?

Comment: Sure, you should put your token, result will be: `'Authorization': 'Bearer adfdskjfdlsfjdsfjdsklfjkdfsdflfjdsfdsf'`, i.e. `var token = 'adfdskjfdlsfjdsfjdsklfjkdfsdflfjdsfdsf'`

Comment: I did it like this,k not working it yet, i dont know why

Comment: Show me response from server with error and make sure that header was sent.

Comment: angular.js:14800 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."},"status":403,"config":

Comment: What Authentication/Authorization workflow do you use?

Comment: My BACKEND IS DJANGO rest api, when i logged in, it generates a authentiacatoin token, i just put that token here only

Comment: Is it access token?

Comment: I dont know, if i logged in, it generates a token.

Comment: I want to let you know one more hint: when i logged in, the GET method working without putting any  headers, only not working POST method

Comment: Without knowing type of authentication I can't help you.

Comment: If you work with cookies you should not pass them manually, cookies will be sent to server by browser automatically. May be your cookies are wrong or empty or not contain necessary for autentication stuff

Comment: OK, I am trying to another way, thank you man, your time is really appreciated